# How to format HTML that's generated from a SharePoint List

Tags: html, pdf, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I followed the directions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0yueT7fBAE) to export a SharePoint List first to an HTML file, and then use that to create a PDF file.  The PowerAutomate 'flow' is shown in the image below.
Although this works, I want to be able to format the HTML table.  As it currently is, the table has no visible **borders**, and the column **widths** are not appropriate.
So...Is there a way I can insert something like this into the flow for the beginning of the HTML file, to provide visible borders?

```
<html><head><style>

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table style="width:100%";
               }
</style></head><body>
```

Or, in the first row () of the table, change this `<th>Minutes</th>` to this: `<th style="width:50%">Minutes</th>`, to set the column width?

If there's another, better way to export the SharePoint List into a PDF I'd love to hear it;  I'm doing it via an HTML file because that's what I've been able to find.
I'm not overly fond of supposedly 'low-code' PowerAutomate so maybe there are better ways?  I'm not familiar with [SharePlum](https://pypi.org/project/SharePlum/) but maybe Python is a better approach?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Power Automate HTML table styling my go-to article is this one from Ryan Maclean: https://ryanmaclean365.com/2020/01/29/power-automate-html-table-styling/

Have a look at that Injecting CSS Styling section of that blog.

Probably not every style will carry over to a PDF when converting the file from HTML to Pdf format. That is something you will have to test yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Expiscornovus for the link, which helped me figure out how to introduce the initial HTML code I wanted to show borders, etc.  If anyone sees this and wants details of what I did...

Basically I initialised a variable (string) and input the HTML code I wanted as the 'value'.

For my second question, how to change the HTML code generated from the Sharepoint List (in my case, to specify column width), I found the video on this page helpful.  What I did was initialise another variable, but here I used the 'replace' expression to substitute `replace(body('Create_HTML_table'),'<th>Minutes</th>','<th style="width:50%">Minutes</th>')`.
The 2 newly interpolated steps are shown below:
[image]